# php-cgi causes permission denied on output file despite appropriate permissions

Tags: permissions, php, sudo

I am trying to run a php script using the php-cgi.  The command is:

```
sudo -Hu apache /usr/bin/php-cgi -f /var/www/html/load.php >> /var/www/html/load.log
```

The output is:

```
-bash: /var/www/html/load.log: Permission denied
```

when I run `ls -la /var/www/html` I get:

```
...
-rwxr--r--  1 apache apache    1 Nov  2 14:00 load.log
```

apache has rwx permission on that file!  why the permission denied?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working when I add w permissions on the file such as:

```
`sudo chmod o+w /var/www/html/load.log`
```

For whatever reason the writing was not being done on behalf of apache.